# How to retrieve all records from related tables?

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, cakephp-2.0

I have a table called "informations" (http://pastebin.com/h3UiUhpx) and also have this associated tables "educations", "attachments" and "experiences" (http://pastebin.com/RdWzfria) (please see pastebin URLs I put the code there to not ugly the post). As you may notice all this tables have a relationship with informations so data coming from informations form is saved there. I use bake for create the models, views and controllers for this tables. Now when I add all is fine except for the attachments because it's a FILE input type and I don't know how to handle this part so any help will be very appreciated but the problem here is when I try to edit any records for informations table because none record from the relations tables is showed and don't know the cause. The code for informations model is here: http://pastebin.com/bEY3beBw, for the Controller is here: http://pastebin.com/muAQn3aH and for the view is here: http://pastebin.com/AEhPPCX0, can any help to fix this?
Cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post on pastebin all other models? Sounds your reference id field is wrong. For related field, you need use on singular, use information_id instead informations_id. Take a look on [database conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `pr($this->request->data)` at the bottom of your edit function of the controller. It will show you that the model data is coming back just fine. You need to correct your `edit.ctp` view to handle the information correctly.

Comment: Thanks to both was mine problem related to FK :-( my bad